# Add a txt file in a database SQLite ( for Android), how?

Tags: android, file, sqlite

Should I put a txt file saved in the phone's sd card in a database SQLite of Android, but I do not know how to do it,  help me and I kindly wrote a few lines of code to do this?

Comment: what purpose do u need it for? Is the data in a tabular format?

Comment: txt is a file containing the tabular data in a non-ordered (not separated by: commas points etc.) I would understand if there's an easy way to remove this file from txt sd card and insert it into a row of a table! Without too many complications, such as a jpg image!

Comment: Follow this exact tutorial and tell us if/when you get stuck http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Have you written the code to read the file in from the SD Card?.  That is the first step. If you need advice on opening reading file, let us know.

Comment: I'm not as point greedy as i may appear.

Comment: @CodeDroid Ha, no worries! When the author responds, it seems you have some get references to help him/her out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `File` to `byte[]` and then add it in the sqlite as `BLOB` data. Perhaps you should convert them to `Base64` format for space optimization and you should be ok.

As you can see there are multiple steps in implementing something like this so I just added the general overview. If you are stuck on something, ask for more detail.

EDIT:
I will provide the code for the key points.

For converting file to byte[] use this snippet:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); // where file is the .txt you want to convert
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((int bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
   bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Convert byte[] to base64 String:

```
String dataToSave = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

OR

```
byte[] dataToSave = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

although you must have at least version 2.2 to support base 64 encoding.

If you have selected the first implementation then any TEXT field in your sqlite table would be enough otherwise create a column in your table as BLOB. And when creating the `ContentValues` you wish to insert, add `values.put(KEY, dataToSave);`.

OBTAINING DATA:

Do the reversed operation: 1)get data from sqlite, 2) convert to byte[], 3) convert to file.

Converting `byte[]` to `File`:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path); //file path as string
out.write(data); //data is the byte[]
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: It seems to me that your approach interesting, could you write a few lines of code on how to do? Thank you!

Comment: very nice, would you be so kind as to insert the code to convert the file bytes to txt file, the reverse operation? thanks again!

Comment: why do you use base encode? i used this and it doesn't seem any different than not using it...

Comment: @AhmedZafar as I said in my answer. You COULD use for space optimisation, not that this is a must. Base64 encoding is basically more space efficient. It converts a byte[] to a similar (smaller) in size byte[] or to a String. Technically, what Base64 does is "unifying" same characters in order to preserve space, more can be found on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 0):

If the text file contains rows of data.  For example

```
 <ISBN>, <Title>, <Author>, <Price>
```

Then you should store this as table in sqLite.  Why?  Because SQLIte is really a file database anyway and once you store as a table in SQLite you can use the power of SQLite to query the data in various ways.  Add remove rows etc.

Follow the steps here and tell us where you get stuck.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If you just want an easy way to save off the value of text you should just read it into a String and save the String using SharePreferences.

In any event, step 1 is to read the file from the SD Card.